# sensorPortait typo

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation

is sensorPortait a typo mistake? I see threads around guiding people to use sensorPortrait but my eclipse works with sensorPortait instead.

Comment: Thank you for this! I couldn't for the life of me figure out why what I was doing wasn't working... turns out its just another platform issue. Google should really add sensorPortrait to AAPT along with sensorPortait.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter - its consistent, also for reversePortait, and as you said, eclipse doesn't let you use sensorPortrait.

But my guess is that someone in Google is copy-pasting too much...

Comment: Yes, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#screenOrientation