# Android: Capture event when orientation change from portrait to reversePortait

Tags: android, orientation-changes, event-capturing

My application supports portrait mode only including the upside down view. Hence I've got the following in the menifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait"
```

Also the following to capture orientation change events:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

But onConfigurationChanged event is not fired with portrait only supported application.

I need to catch the event when the application changes orientation from normal portrait to reverse portrait. Any idea?

Comment: there is a typo in "sensorPort(r)ait". If you copied and pasted from your source, then I would try again.

Comment: Actually there is no 'r'. It's android:screenOrientation="sensorPortait" 
Copy-pasted from my source.

Comment: lol, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964848/sensorportait-typo :) nvm.

Comment: I see. Anyway, it says it doesn't matter. My application also works alright (view changes from normal to reverse and vice-versa on device orientation change). Problem is event is not fired.

Comment: there was a bug which was fixed in sdk 15. dumb google :P